# Linking to external files on AGOL in Windows 10

Tags: arcgis-online, windows-10

I have a link field in a feature layer on AGOL. I want to link to files that reside on my desktop. When I click on the link nothing happens. If I copy the link to IE or Chrome, I get a search page list of options, not the file I want. This is a sample link that I am trying to use: "file:\aiotxtem3fp1\geodata$\elevation\Texas_Lidar_1m\Rasters\Texas_Lidar\USGS_NED_ArcherJack_1m_2014\USGS_NED_one_meter_x50y370_TX_Archer_Jack_2014_IMG_2016". The word "file" preceding the link is recommended by ESRI. I set this configuration up last July and this link worked perfectly: "\aiotxtem3fp1\geodata$\elevation\Texas_Lidar_1m\Rasters\Texas_Lidar\USGS_NED_ArcherJack_1m_2014\USGS_NED_one_meter_x50y370_TX_Archer_Jack_2014_IMG_2016" before the newest upgrade in AGOL and Windows 10.  Any ideas or suggestions as to the problem or a solution.  I don't have access to a server to put my files on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Check out the support article to learn more: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012221

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to directly linking from a local drive is to upload the file for ArcGIS Online to host in a field. To do this, enable image attachments for the layer from the item details page:

[image: Image Attachment]

Thereafter, you should open the item in the Map Viewer, open its attribute table, and scroll horizontally to the end to find a new field called 'Photos and Files'. You'll be able to upload images from your desktop through the 'Add' button (or the 'Show' button after you've added some images).

[image: Add Images]

Don't forget to save the layer when you're done.